# Pick image from gallery, including Picasa/AutoBackup images

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, image-gallery

I am dealing with Pick gallery images and show them in app also save their Path for some references in future.

I was able to Pick those images from gallery which are stored on device like in some folder like Downloads by this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionPick, Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
intent.SetType ("image/*");
StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (intent, "Select photo"), 0);
```

and in Result:

```
public override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

case 0:
          string FilePath = GetPathToImage (data.Data);
}

private string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            string path = null;
            string[] projection = new[] { Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
                using (ICursor cursor = this.Activity.ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null))
                {
                    if (cursor != null)
                    {
                        int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                        cursor.MoveToFirst();
                        path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return uri.Path;
                    }
                }
}
```

**My question is** : I am able to get paths of images those are placed in some local folder in gallery, but for folders like **Picasa/Autobackup** I am not able to get Path.

Note:For local images path starts from content://
     For Other com.android....like that.

So, Is there any workaround to get paths of those images.

I **don't** want to do like this to just display image:

```
final InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
```

**I need a Path.**

If there is no solution, then **How can we skip those images being displayed while Picking** from Gallery/Photos.

PS: [Known Issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21234)

Any Suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: check this out https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

Comment: Checked that...not seems to be supported for Xamarin